# Use JavaScript to automatically fill in HTML forms

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to automate a test routine in a web application. My goal is to fill forms, submit them and get the html returned by the application after the form is submited. In other words, i want to simulate what a human would do, but as i need to do this in dozens of forms, i want to do it automatically using pure JS (no frameworks).

For instance, a login form i'm trying to submit looks like this :

[image]

To fill the form i'm using a code like this :

document.getElementById('username').value = 'test@test.com';
document.getElementById('password').value = 'mypassord';

But it seems the information is not being correctly filled ; after i run the code above, the form looks like this :

[image]

As you can see, the placeholder is still on the inputs and if i submit the form, the input values are not submited. It seems the 'value = 'xxx'' is not effectively filling the field.

It only works if i manually input something on the keyboard after running the code above.

What else can i try ?

Thanks !

Comment: try changing the `placeholder` to `''`

Answer (score 3):

Here is the complete code. Run on your browser hope it will works for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" placeholder="This is text Field" id="txtField">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Input password" id="txtPass">
  <script>
    document.getElementById('txtField').value = 'test@test.com';
    document.getElementById('txtPass').value = 'test@123';
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you but only pure JS allowed : /

Comment: This woks for me(Pure JS): 
 <input type="text" placeholder="This is text Field" id="txtField">
 <input type="password" placeholder="Input password" id="txtPass">
 <script>
  document.getElementById('txtField').value = 'test@test.com'; 
  document.getElementById('txtPass').value = 'test@test.com'; 
 </script>

Comment: This is exactly what i'm doing and although the input is filled, the error i show on the question happens (placeholder still active and inputs not sent)

Comment: @delphirules Please provide the HTML code for the input

Comment: @smileycreations15 In this example is the Instagram's login page at https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login